# How to make my code insensitive to acronyms

Tags: python, html, django, acronym

I'm creating a website that shows available carparks in each college campus. How do I make the code insensitive to acronyms, e.g.g if the name of the campus is DCU Alpha?

carparks.html

```
<h2>
{% if campus %}
{{ campus }}
{% else %}
No such campus
{% endif %}
</h2>
{% if campus %}
{% if carparks %}
<ul>
{% for carpark in carparks %}
<li>{{carpark.name}}: {{carpark.spaces}} spaces, {{carpark.disabled_spaces}} spaces for people with disabilities
  <br>Spaces available:  {{ carpark.spaces_available }}<br><br>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No carparks found</p>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
def carparks(request):
    context = {}
    Base_URL = 'http://jfoster.pythonanywhere.com/carparks/'
    campus_name = request.GET['campus']
    try:
       campus = Campus.objects.get(name__iexact=campus_name)
    except Campus.DoesNotExist:
       return render(request,"parkatdcu/carparks.html",context)
    carparks = Carpark.objects.filter(campus_id=campus)
    carpark_info = []
    for carpark in carparks:
        URL = Base_URL + carpark.name
        r = requests.get(URL).json()
        if 'spaces_available' in r:
            spaces_available = r['spaces_available']
        else:
            spaces_available = 'not available'
        carpark_info.append({
                         'name': carpark.name,
                         'spaces': carpark.spaces,
                         'disabled_spaces': carpark.disabled_spaces,
                         'spaces_available': spaces_available
                         }
                        )
        context['campus'] = campus_name.title()
        context['carparks'] = carpark_info
        return render(request,"parkatdcu/carparks.html",context)
```

Comment: Can you share where exactly you're running into an issue?

Comment: At the moment the code works perfectly, it's just when I search for carpark information for DCU Alpha, the page says 'Dcu Alpha'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Original Answer: String Manipulation

You can force uppercase strings in python / javascript like so:

**python**

```py
# becomes DCU ALPHA
'dcu alpha'.upper()
 
# becomes Dcu Alpha
'dcu alpha'.capitalize()

# becomes DCU Alpha: 
'dcu alpha'.split(' ')[0].upper() + ' ' + 'dcu alpha'.split(' ')[1].captialize()
```

**javascript**

```js
// becomes DCU ALPHA:
'dcu alpha'.toUpperCase()

// becomes DCU Alpha:
'dcu alpha'.slice(0, 5).toUpperCase() + 'dcu alpha'.slice(5,)
```

## EDIT: Conditional Formatting:

Let's assume we have campus names like so:

```
campuses = ['dcu alpha', 'northridge', 'lsu univiersity', 'princeton', ...]
```

We can add some logic to check for campuses's with acrononyms:

**views.py**

```py
# check if a campus contains two words:
if len(campus_name.split(' ')) > 1: 
    # campus name has at least two words
else: 
    # campus name has only one word
```

We can also create two lists, one with campus names that have acronyms and one with campus names that do not:

```py
# set two lists:
campuses_with_acronyms = ['dcu alpha', 'lsu univiersity', ...]
campuses_without_acronyms = ['northride', 'princeton', ...]

# check if the campus name is in either list:
if campus_name in campuses_with_acronyms:
    # campus name has an acronym
else:
    # campus name does not have an acronym
```

Comment: Where can I put this solution?

Comment: I put the Python solution in my views.py file below the line                        
context['campus'] = campus_name.title(). But now it says 'index error' when I put in a name that doesn't start with an acronym, e.g. Glasnevin. So how do I fix that?

Comment: You need to add some additional logic to check for campus names that have / do not have acronyms - see my edited answer for some ideas.

Comment: I put this in my views.py                                                                                                                    if len(campus_name.split()) > 1:
        context['campus'] = campus_name.split(' ')[0].upper() + ' ' + campus_name.split(' ')[1].title()
    else:
        context['campus'] = campus_name.title()                                                                     So now how do I fix it for campus names that don't have an acronym, e.g. All Hallows?

Comment: How do you determine which campuses have and which do not have acronyms?

Comment: Maybe I could put the campus names in a dictionary?